# DNN module uninstall how to remove settings from web.config

Tags: web-config, settings, dotnetnuke, manifest, uninstallation

I have a DNN manifest file with this:

```
<configuration>
<nodes>
<node path="/configuration/appSettings" action="update" key="key"    collision="overwrite">
<add key="LocalCurrencyCode" value="ARS"/>
</node>
```

and for uninstall I have this:

```
<uninstall>
<configuration>
<nodes>
<node path="/configuration/appsettings/add[@name='LocalCurrencyCode']" action="remove" />
```

However, when I uninstall the module the setting is not removed from web.config.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it:

```
 <uninstall>
          <configuration>
            <nodes>
              <node path="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='InvoiceEmailSubject']" action="remove" />
```

Turns out that I needed "appSettings" because xml nodes are case sensitive. I also needed to use @key= as provided by Dexterity above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to replace `@name` with `@key` in `<uninstall>` section like this. There are no any `name` attribute in `appsettings`.

```
<node path="/configuration/appsettings/add[@key='LocalCurrencyCode']" action="remove" />
```